# How to start windows explorer with taskbar in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

I need to update my shell dll and to make sure that it is not in use, I am killing current windows explorer process using taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe command.

But when I try to start explorer again it don't bring back taskbar, I search for different solutions that brings taskbar back, but problem with them is that It is working on Windows 8.1, 10 but on Windows 7 64 bit, somehow it is not starting and that also randomly(sometime it do start).

Below are the solutions that I tried:

Solution 1:

```
Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.SystemDirectory) + "\\Explorer.exe");
```

Solution 2:

```
RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

RegistryKey regKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
regKey.SetValue("Shell", "explorer.exe", RegistryValueKind.String);
regKey.Close();

Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\..\\explorer.exe");
```

Solution 3:

```
var ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
string anyCommand = "%systemroot%\\sysnative\\cmd.exe /c start /B explorer.exe";
ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory), "Windows\\System32");

ProcessStartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory), "Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
//ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + anyCommand;
ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
using (var exeProcess = Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo))
{
    if (exeProcess != null)
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a file that is in use, you can always rename the existing file and copy the new version with the original name next to the existing one.

Then there is the Windows API call (name escapes me) that allows you to schedule the deletion of the renamed file on reboot.

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion, but after reading this blog I don't consider that as a good option. https://marc.durdin.net/2011/09/why-you-should-not-use-movefileex-with-movefile_delay_until_reboot-2/